# Displaying html table on post content

Tags: html

I generated some content via golang. Than I added to wordpress wp_posts table. The generated content contains html table element. But I can not display properly on frontend area. there is problem at rendering table. All table,tr and td tags had removed. My sample link is : [sample link](http://tabanpuanlar.site/karabuk-lise-taban-puanlari/)

[image: browser]

[image: post content source code]

Comment: Your html table not wellformed, no `td` element.

Comment: You added to the wp_posts table?  How?  And how are you attempting to render this?

Comment: @Jevuska thank you. I did not write table properly.